# Why related field not showing value on view in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I am working on point of sale where i need to display 'Payment Journal'(Cash / Cheque) and statement id (statement) from 'Accounting' module which containing these fields only not POS. S o need to display in tree view of Point of sale(orders) list.
here is my code i tried :

```
journal_ids = fields.Many2one('account.journal', string='Journal', readonly=True, domain=[('type', 'in', ('bank', 'cash'))])
journal_id = fields.Char(related='journal_ids.type', store=True)
```

Comment: Check if `journal_ids` has value, plus make sure they are visible in view

Comment: And a little hint: use the odoo coding guidelines. The first field should be named `journal_id` while the second should be called `journal_name` (or something in that way, nothing in the guideline).

Comment: Still can't display value in tree view. Is there any way to access field of one model to another model's view ?

Comment: Could you post your xml code?.

Comment: <tree string="POS Orders" decoration-info="state == 'draft'" decoration-muted="state in ('done','cancel')" create="0">
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="partner_id"/>
                <field name="date_order"/>
                <field name="journal_id" />widget="monetary"/>
                <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company"/>
                <field name="state"/>
                <field name="session_id" />
            </tree>

Comment: `<field name="journal_id" />widget="monetary"/>` is not properly coded

Comment: Removed extra  "widget='monetary'

Answer (score 0):

This is working in base "**Point of Sale**".. You can take reference from "**account_journal_view.xml**" In this you get to know that they are just using tree view of account model in POS "**Payment Method**" menu.  Just inherit this in your custom module add fields what you want to add using  tag in tree view and you get result what you want.